# What is the Sod HaIbbur and what is so secret about it?

Tags: halacha-theory, calendar, science, months, moon

What is the Sod HaIbbur (secret of impregnation)? I have seen it discussed in many places including the Pirkeu D'Rebbi Eliezer (8th chapter?) in reference to the intercalation for the lunar months of the year and applying a leap month (which creates an "impregnated" year) so that the lunar calendar doesn't continually fall behind the solar one.

If all this is, is the mathematics behind the lunar calendar, why is it a secret? Does this secret continue to exist now that we have a set calendar? Is there another interpretation of Sod HaIbbur?

Comment: Of course it still exists as a secret! How many people do you know that have actually read through all of Rambam's Hilchot Kiddush haChodesh??

Comment: @DoubleAA - I'm approaching that, slowly but surely. Having MS Excel around makes understanding the math a bit easier ... a BIT.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Breslev.org](http://www.breslev.org/pages.php?subaction=showfull&id=1202929773&ucat=36) Sod HaIbbur includes all the secrets of the Torah "סוד העיבור בו כלולים כל סודות התורה".
All difficult questions such as Bechira, Why we are the chosen nation, are answered by the Sod HaIbbur - per Rabbi Nosson M'Breslov.

The Sod HaIbbur also includes Wisdom and knowledge pertaining to changes and the the future that are pertaining to the heavenly wheels 
 "חכמת תהלוכי הרקיע, לידע כל ההשתנות ועתידות הבאין על ידי גלגלי הרקיע".

Comment: The latter sentence just means: the science of astronomy.

Comment: @DoubleAA עתידות הבאין על ידי גלגלי הרקיע sounds more like astrology

Answer (score 1):

During certain pressing times, the secret of these calculations were used when other means couldn’t be verified or were questionable, and thus they didn’t want this secret to get out so that it can be implemented when necessary, hence its name - *secret*.

**Hamaor Hakatan, Rosh Hashana 20b
(Rif, p. 14 in OzVehadar)**

> וזה הוא סוד העיבור בדחיית מולד זקן שהוא לאחר י " ז שעות תתרע " ט חלקים שהוא נדחה בכל ראשי שנים לעולם ואין לנו בימים הראויים לקביעת ראש השנה שהם ימי בגה " ז כי אם שתי דחיות אחרות והם בשנים הפשוטות הדחייה האחת בט " ו תקפ " ט לאחר מעוברת והשנית ג " ט ו " ך בכל שנה פשוטה והמולד הזקן הוא נדחה לעולם ושרש דחייתו מן ההלכה הזאת והוא מסור בידינו על פי החשבון בסוד העבור מימי הלל בן יהודה בן גמליאל בן רבינו הקדוש שהנהיג לקדש ע " פ החשבון וע " פ הראיה מדוחק הגלות שלא היו העדים מצויין ללכת להעיד לפני בית דין ולא השלוחים לכל המקומות יכולין לצאת להודיע קדוש בית דין משום שבוש דרכים אבל בדורות הראשונים שהיו מקדשין ע " פ הראייה לא היינו נוהגים בסוד הזה שאנו נוהגים בו אלא שאפשר שיסמכו עליו בשעת הדחק כמו שנהגנו אנו לסמוך עליו ועל כן שאלנו בגמרא למאי נפקא מינה כלומר מה איכפת להם לדורות הראשונים להיות מחשבין תולדת הלבנה תדיר והלא הם לא היו מקדשים אלא ע " פ הראיה ובאה התשובה על השאלה זאת נפקא מינה לאכחושי סהדי כי מחשבון המולד אתה יכול לדעת שעת הראיה שהיא לאחר מיכן בכ " ד שעות כמו שאמרנו ואם העידו העדים שראו את החדש קודם הזמן הזה הרי הם מוכחשים וזה הוא הצורך לחשבון המולד בכל זמן ובכל מקום שהיו מקדשים ע " פ הראייה ואפילו בחוצה לארץ כעקיבא בן יוסף וחנניה בן אחי רבי יהושע שהיו מעברים שנים וקובעין חדשים בחוצה לארץ כמו שמפורש במסכת ברכות [ סג ] זה הוא הצורך לחשבון וזה הצורך הגלוי וידוע לכל אבל הסוד היה לקבוע על פיו בשעת הדחק ולכך נקרא סוד שלא היו רוצין לגלותו ולפרש דבריו וטעמו למה נמסר החשבון כנגד מקום אחד והראיה כנגד מקום אחר לפי שהיה להם כדבר מוצנע לעת הצורך ולשעת הדחק וכל חכם ומבין בחשבון יכול הוא להוציא חשבון זה מחשבון זה בכל מקום ובכל זמן כפי מה שיצטרך וכפי מה שפירשנו והרי השלמנו פירוש שתי השמועות הקשות והם קשורות ותלויות זו בזו :

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of סוד העיבור in the Talmud is "Council of Intercalation".  Sacha Stern, *Calendar and Community*, Oxford University Press, 2001, p. 190.  It refers to the calendrical court.  The meaning "secret of intercalation" arose later.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, like Psalms 111:1. But how could he know that? Is he speculating or does he have some sort of proof?

Comment: @DoubleAA His reasoning: its pretty clear usage in Ketubot 112a; in RH 20b it doesn't seem particularly secret if it's in the name of a Babylonian Amora; the likelier sense of Sheilta 67 (בזמן חכמי' הראשוני' שהיו בקיאין בחשבון מולד לבנה ובדיקדוקי סוד העיבור).

Comment: @magicker72 Thanks, it's definitely not a bad read at all of those sources but also doesn't seem like a 100% proof.

Comment: @DoubleAA I see he also cites a letter from R. Saadiah (or a colleague) that says כבר עלו כמה חכמים מבבל אל ארץ ישר׳ ודקדקו עם חכמי ארץ ישר׳ בסוד העיבור ופשפשו וחיפשו בזו עד שנתבוננו בו יפה יפה. He admits that many of these could be read either way, but he prefers "council" or similar.